# login runs with admin.html but no with client .html

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have that javascript code in app.js with jwt and session to authenticate admin or no admin (client). In local mode, all runs well but with web host, I have an internal error, if you have a suggestion to solve the problem, thanks, here's the following message ot the web host server :

```
Checking whether to disconnect long-running connections for process 70002, application VBJ (production) at Function process_params 
App 70002 output:     at /home/c2100699c/VBJ/app.js:229:5
App 70002 output:     at isValidCredentials (/home/c2100699c/VBJ/app.js:244:14)
```

Here is my code in app.js

```
// Middleware pour vérifier l'authentification avec JWT
function verifyToken(req, res, next) {
  const token = req.cookies.token || '';
  jwt.verify(token, 'secret', function (err, decoded) {
    if (err) {
      return res.redirect('/login.html');
    } else {
      req.decoded = decoded;
      next();
    }
  });
}

// Route pour le login
app.post('/auth', function (req, res) {
  const username = req.body.username;
  const password = req.body.password;
  const email = req.body.email;
  console.log('Request data:', username, password, email);

  if ((username === '***********' && email === '*****************') && password === '*********') {
    const token = jwt.sign({
      username,
      email,
      role: 'admin'
    }, 'secret', {
      expiresIn: '1h'
    });
    res.cookie('token', token, {
      httpOnly: true
    });
    return res.redirect('/admin.html');
  } else {
    isValidCredentials(username, password, email, function (valid, isAdmin) {
      if (valid) {
        const role = isAdmin ? 'admin' : 'client';
        const token = jwt.sign({
          username,
          email,
          role
        }, 'secret', {
          expiresIn: '1h'
        });
        res.cookie('token', token, {
          httpOnly: true
        });
        return res.redirect('/client.html');
      } else {
        return res.redirect('/login.html');
      }
    });
  }
});

function isValidCredentials(username, password, email, callback) {
  const query = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? AND password = ? AND email = ? AND administrateur = 0';
  connection.query(query, [username, password, email], function (error, results, fields) {
    if (error)
      throw error;
    if (results.length > 0) {
      const isAdmin = results[0].administrateur === 1;
      callback(true, isAdmin);
    } else {
      callback(false, false);
    }
  });
}

// Route pour la page d'administration
app.get('/admin', verifyToken, function (req, res) {
  if (req.session.loggedin) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/admin.html');
  } else {
    res.send('Veuillez vous connecter pour accéder à cette page');
  }
  res.end();
});

// Route pour la page client
app.get('/client', verifyToken, function (req, res) {
  if (req.session.loggedin) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client.html');
  } else {
    res.send('Veuillez vous connecter pour accéder à cette page');
  }
  res.end();
});
```

and my code in login.js

```
const loginForm = document.getElementById('login');
submit.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  login();
});

function login() {
  const username = document.getElementById('username').value;
  const password = document.getElementById('password').value;
  const email = document.getElementById('emailRegister').value;

  fetch('/auth', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      username,
      password,
      email
    })
  })
  .then(res => {
    console.log('Response status:', res.status);
    console.log('Response headers:', res.headers);
    return res.json();
  })
  .then(data => {
    console.log('Response data:', data);
    if (data.userType === 'administrateur') {
      window.location.href = '/admin.html';
    } else if (data.userType === 'client') {
      window.location.href = '/client.html';
    } else {
      document.querySelector("#message2").innerText = "Identifiant, email ou mot de passe incorrect";
    }
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log('Error:', error);
  });
}
```

Comment: You are possibly throwing an error you never catch, when your query runs into an error (at least not in the code shown here) Any additional outputs in the logs? And just as a sidenote: In your query you have the condition `and administrateur = 0` but 2 lines later you are checking if `results[0].administrateur === 1` Assuming, that your email/usernames are unique, that will never be true

Comment: If it runs fine on local but not on the server, I can only suggest to add additional logging output, so that you can can see what's really going on. Ie which part of the code are reached, where it breaks, log error messages ...)

Comment: ok. thanks but the error is located in the following line : connection.query(query, [username, password, email], function (error, results, fields) {
    if (error)